# Why the Azure Event Hub get events so slow?

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-eventhub

Event Hub is fast to send but slow to get. I use next code:

```js
    subscribe(cb: (event: any) => Promise<void>) {
        this.consumerClient.subscribe(
            this.config.partitionId,
            {
                processEvents: async (events: any, context: any) => {
                    if (events.length === 0) {
                        return;
                    }

                    for (const event of events) {
                        await cb(event.body);
                    }

                    await context.updateCheckpoint(events[events.length - 1]);
                },

                processError: async (err, context: any) => {
                    console.error(`Event Hub Subscribe Error`, { err, context });
                },
            },
            { startPosition: earliestEventPosition },
        );
    }
```

It takes about 1 minute to get 100 events. The `await cb(event.body);` works fast.

Comment: You can refer to [receiveEventsUsingCheckpointStore.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/eventhubs-checkpointstore-blob/samples/v1/javascript/receiveEventsUsingCheckpointStore.js) and [receiveEvents.js](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/2f90a8781fc87246a80e0e14b3563db7c2b92ef0/sdk/eventhub/event-hubs/samples/v5/javascript/receiveEvents.js)

Comment: [Receive events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-node-get-started-send#write-code-to-receive-events), [Scaling with Event Hubs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-scalability#throughput-units) and [Azure Event Hubs quotas and limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-quotas)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "maxBatchSize" and "maxWaitTimeInSeconds" in the subscribe options:

```
subscribe(cb: (event: any) => Promise<void>) {
    this.consumerClient.subscribe(
        this.config.partitionId,
        {
            processEvents: async (events: any, context: any) => {
                if (events.length === 0) {
                    return;
                }

                for (const event of events) {
                    await cb(event.body);
                }

                await context.updateCheckpoint(events[events.length - 1]);
            },

            processError: async (err, context: any) => {
                console.error(`Event Hub Subscribe Error`, { err, context });
            },
        },
        { 
             startPosition: earliestEventPosition,
             maxBatchSize: 50,
             maxWaitTimeInSeconds: 1
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue must be from the source side, not in Event Hub since it is sending the data at expected speed.

Here are some recommendations in the light of the performance and throughput results:

- If events do not naturally comes in batch of many events:  simply
  stream events.  Do not try to batch them unless network IO is
  constrained.
- If a latency of 0.1 seconds is a concern:  move the call to Event
  Hubs away from your critical performance path.

Refer [Performance and scale for Event Hubs and Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/serverless/event-hubs-functions/performance-scale) to know more on how the performance can be improved.